# Excel dynamic row

Tags: excel, numbers, row

Hi i am using these formulas to extract some data from one sheet to another.

```
='[test.xlsx]Some Fantastic Sheet Name'!A1

='[test.xlsx]Some Fantastic Sheet Name'!B1

='[test.xlsx]Some Fantastic Sheet Name'!C1
```

I got number (1) in cell for example D1. Is it posible to change row numbers in formulas by changing the number in cell D1? ...So when D1 is 2 it will look like this:

```
='[test.xlsx]Some Fantastic Sheet Name'!A2

='[test.xlsx]Some Fantastic Sheet Name'!B2

='[test.xlsx]Some Fantastic Sheet Name'!C2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

This is a non Volatile formula(INDIRECT and OFFSET are Volatile)

```
=INDEX('[test.xlsx]Some Fantastic Sheet Name'!A:A,D1)
```

Comment: I was about to start on `Indirect()`, but this is much better since you can use a closed workbook. Nice thinking!  Only note is OP may need to change the index column, depending. Right now, he can drag across, but not down.

Comment: I have tryed to copy that but it says my formula is incorrect :/

Comment: Do you use `;` instead of `,` as the deliminator between criteria in your formulas?

Comment: I got only one formila in one cell.

Comment: @Majlo for example if you were to use the IF formula would you do `=IF(1=1,2,0)` or would you use `=IF(1=1;2;0)`

Comment: I think i use this one ;

Comment: Then replace the `,` after the `A:A` with `;` @Majlo

Comment: @Majlo please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.